# Prove that $\det(A+B)\det(A-B)=0$

Tags: matrices, determinant, transpose

Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices with real entries, where $n$ is odd, such that $A\cdot A^{t}=I_n$ and $B\cdot B^{t}=I_n$. Prove that $$\det(A+B)\det(A-B)=0$$
It is obvious that $A^{-1}=A^{t}$ and $B^{-1}=B^{t}$, so $\det A, \det B = \pm 1$. Then I tried to write $\det(A+B)\det(A-B)=\det(A^2-AB+BA-B^2)$, but I didn't get anything useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}\det(A+B)\det(A-B)&=\det(A+B)\det(A^T-B^T) \\ &= \det(AA^T+BA^T-AB^T-BB^T)\\&=\det(BA^T-AB^T)\end{aligned}$$

Now use the assumption that $n$ is odd and the fact that $C=BA^T-AB^T$ is skew-symmetric: $C=-C^T$.

Comment: Very nice argument! Note that it uses only $AA^T = BB^T $, rather than the orthogonality of the two matrices.

Answer (score 0):

We know that...
$(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-AB+BA-B^2$
So $det[(A+B)(A-B)]=d(A^2-AB+BA-B^2)≠0 $ in general.
Which is possible when $A,B$ be the involuntary matrix.
i.e $A=A^{-1},B=B^{-1}$,then $A$ and $B$ are commutative i.e $AB=BA$ and $A^2=I_n,B^2=I_n$.
Hence in this case...
$det[(A+B)(A-B)]=det(A+B)det(A-B)=det(I_n-AB+AB-I_n)=0$.
If I mistake please tell me.

Comment: We don't have $A=A^{-1}$, but $A^{t}=A^{-1}$